# How to reset Outlook 2007 to access email links

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

With a new install of Windows 7, all is well except that in Outlook 2007 all email links will not activate. Keep getting the error message that the action is not allowed "...see administrator".  I've tried several suggestions and searched system, Outlook, IE (2008) to fix this with no good results. Any more guide lines would be appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: you're saying that when you receive an email message that contains an email link, and you then click on that link, you get an error message saying that the "action is not allowed" and to "see administrator."  Is that correct?  Also, if you could post the error message verbatim that would be helpful.